# What is the Background blur property in css?

Tags: css

Which is property used to blur the background in css?

styling through filter.
I want to add background picture in html code and then requirement is that to blur that image for better styling . suggest me the better option for that and also initial value for the property.

Comment: Provide your code, what you have did till now?

Answer (score 0):

The backdrop-filter CSS property lets you apply graphical effects such as blurring or color shifting to the area behind an element. Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect the element or its background needs to be transparent or partially transparent.